# Simple flash card app satisfying certain criteria

Tags: flashcard

I am looking for simple flash card app to memorise words of another language I am learning that

- would be open-sourced (I don't mind a closed-source app unless they feed you with pesky ads; I don't mind paying a few bucks as well, but I must be sure I really like the stuff).
- could be used out-of-the-box without learning how to do that (like, for example, Anki).
- would allow me create decks of cards (mostly on my computers, but occasionally on my phone as well) that I could have access on any of the devices.
- would automatically shuffle the decks after each use, so the cards would be shown in another (random) order next time.
- would allow decks to be merged and certain cards to be deleted.
- could be used both ways, by that I mean I could choose whether to see either words of the language A to check if I can remember its translation to the language B or to use it the other way around.

I am not interested in seeing statistics or knowing my speed of learning or having internal links between cards or whatever that makes developers to be so proud of their work.

I trust Anki can do all I need and much more (which I don't need). It is just that I have this feeling I read too much manuals and watched too many introduction videos in my life.

Answer (score 1):

The answer came in form of the software called Cram (https://www.cram.com/). It meets almost all the criteria I listed above.